# Preventing Duplicate emails in Firebase Users Table

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, firebase-security, next-auth

**Firbase User Table Data**

```
bet:0
email:"balgia2@gmail.com"
image:"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocK14K75GAfY9OgIU3vl93QaGMQCn4Y90Hu8Nk4I8SEQ=s96-c"
name:"balal 442"
status:"offline"
```

```
bet:500
email:"balgia2@gmail.com"
image:"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocK14K75GAfY9OgIU3vl93QaGMQCn4Y90Hu8Nk4I8SEQ=s96-c"
name:"balal 442"
status:"ingame"
```

**CODE**

```
    import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
    import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
    import {db} from "../../..//Firebase";
    import { collection,query,where,getDocs,addDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
    import changeStatus from '../../../functions/changeStatus';
    var id = "";
    var name = "";
    var phonenumber = "";
    var image = "";
    const usersRef = collection(db, "users");

    export default NextAuth({
        providers:[
            GoogleProvider({
                clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
                clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET
            }),
        ],
        callbacks: {
            async session(session, user) {
                try {
                    if (!db) {
                        throw new Error('An Error Occured');
                    }
                    const usersQuery = query(usersRef, where("email", "==", session.session.user.email));
                    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(usersQuery);
                    if (querySnapshot.docs.length === 0) {
                        const data = {
                            email: session.session.user.email,
                            name : session.session.user.name,
                            image : session.session.user.image,
                            status: "afk",
                            bet: 0
                        }
                        const docRef = await addDoc(usersRef, data);
                        id = docRef.id;
                        session.session.user.id = id;
                    }else{
                        const userData = querySnapshot.docs[0].data();
                        const user = {
                        ...userData
                        };
                        id = querySnapshot.docs[0].id;
                        name = user.name;
                        phonenumber = user.phonenumber;
                        image = user.image;
                        session.session.user.id = id;
                        session.session.user.name = name;
                        session.session.user.phonenumber = phonenumber;
                        session.session.user.image = image;
                    }
                    session.session.user.status = "afk"
                    session.session.user.bet = 0
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log("Error:", error);
                    throw new Error("Something went wrong!");
                }
            
            return session;
            },
        },
        secret: "myawesomesecret"
    })
```

**Firebase Security Rules**

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

One way is that I tried checking the connection with the Firebase before adding the user but it still gave me the same results. Another way is that I tried putting some security rules but I couldn't write down the code. Please supply me with the code.

Comment: It's not possible to prevent duplicate fields between documents. Only the document ID must be unique within a collection (note there no tables in Firestore, just collections). You should consider instead identifying users by their assigned unique ID and not something like an email address which is not case sensitive and could change by the user's choice.

Comment: the collection is called tables and the email is case-sensitive in my case. what is happening is the creation of multiple records for one user when passing the sessions with the same email but different IDs @DougStevenson

Comment: It doesn't really matter what you use case is.  Firestore still doesn't have any way to stop you from putting two documents in a collection with the same value for a field.  You have to stop yourself from doing that by checking before each write.